# Do I keep the Mysql connection alive or close it and open again?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm writing a code in PHP and JS for a project that will request data from a remote database every minute. 
The PHP makes the connection and return the data from my MYSQL database, and the JS is responsible for printing this data on my website and requesting it again.
My doubt is: On the PHP file, do I keep the connection with the database server alive or close it and open it again every minute?

I'm sorry about my english.

Comment: Even if you don't close it you'll lose the reference to the connection anyway when you reload the script, so why does it matter? Just close it.

Comment: best practice is to close open connection once you are done

Comment: Is this a long running PHP script or an AJAX call that your polling every minute from Javascript? Or are you maybe using sockets? If you're polling a script every minute, it's no only best practice to open and close, it's the only way you *can* do it since the connection will close automatically when the script finishes.

Comment: Have you benchmarked your script and found the connection establishment to be particularly costly…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems your application is a web page. That means that the web server serving it will run a PHP process for each request and then it will die and so the connection will get closed with it.
Your question applies better to CLI applications specially if running in daemon mode.

**UPDATE**: as per @deceze comment "*it's perfectly possible to have a persistent PHP script backing a web server… it's just not the default MO*".

Comment: Weeeeelllll… it's perfectly possible to have a persistent PHP script backing a web server… it's just not the default MO, and OP would probably know if they had such an architecture.

Comment: Correct, but that persistent script is not part of the apache process.

Answer (score -1):

close operation Releases the Connection object's database and resources immediately. so if you have alot of computation on the open connection and extracted the full result from database etc, you may want to close the connection since this brings down the performance on the server. but if you don't have alot of computation on the connection you can keep it open until a trigger making it close(this trigger can be anything really, from a button like logging out to creating a timer for closing the connection).